# Get the exact selected value from listbox in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Here is My HTML code

select size="10" id="myselection" multiple ng-multiple="true" ng-model="selectedColors" ng-options="c.name for c in colors" style="width: 150px" 

        Selected Colors: {{selectedColors }}

My javascript code is

function MyCtrl($scope) {

```
$scope.test = "Das ist ein Test";
$scope.colors = [{name: 'black'},
                 {name: 'white'},
                 {name: 'red'},
                 {name: 'blue'},
                 {name: 'yellow'}
];

/*$scope.selectedColors = [$scope.colors[1],$scope.colors[3]];*/
$scope.selectedColors = [$scope.colors[1]];

$scope.doCustom=function() {
    $('#myselection').select2();
};
```

}

the out put i'm getting :
Selected Colors: [{"name":"white"}]

but i need output like :
Selected Colors: white

how to get it. any one please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to repeat over your selectedColors array

```
Selected Colors: <span ng-repeat="for color in selectedColors">{{color.name}}</span>
```

Comment: but i need only the color that is selected. if i use repeat it give all colors right?

Comment: Then you would be fine with {{selectedColors.name}} instead of {{selectedColors}} in your code, I just assumed since you are using a multiple select that you should be able to select several colors.

Comment: ya i got it. can you tell me how to pass that value as a parameter. example <div> ac-chart="chartType" ac-data="black" ac-config="config" id='chart' class='chart'></div> in this instead of black we need to pass the value what we get from list box.

Comment: Yes you should be able to write is in the attibute values by using the double curly braces syntax, like so: ac-data={{selectedColors.name}}" However you might have to get you chart to update when that value change depending on the implementation of the chart.

Comment: And you have tried writing ac-data="selectedColors.name" ? (I just realized that you are using angular-charts and it might work that way instead)